# pygame collision detection between circular sector and rect?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, collision-detection

Want to make something that checks the collision between the sector of a circle and a rect. I checked a lot on the internet but I didn't find any python code or explanation, so I made one and am going to try to explain.

The code I use is on github:

https://github.com/Ieatdedbabies/test (don't mind the names please)

Answer (score 0):

so the logic behind it is 3 step:

1. if one the line of the rect cross a line of the sector, there is collision
2. if the center of the rect is inside the sector, there is collision
3. if the crossing point of the line between the center of the circle the sector make and the center of the rect and any line of the rect is inside the vector, there is collision, exemple: [image: collision 3]

read the README on github for more information and play around my program to understand more